# CoreData doesn't keep the sequence while saveContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to insert data in CoreData. I have may records to insert, this should be all or none. So I am creating instance of `NSManagedObject` and inserting it to `NSManagedObjectContext` one by one.

When I call below method after inserting all records:

```
[_myManagedObjectContext saveContext:&error];
```

This method save all inserted records to persistent store. When I open the Sqlite file generated by core data, I found all the records inserted by my app.

Problem is the order is not same. e.g I inserted records based on serial number 1-100 in sequense, I am able to see random sequence in CoreData sqlite file.

I know that I should not worry about the entries on core data sqlite file I can always fetch records in sorted order using `NSPredicate` but I need to keep the sequence because in some circumstances I need to study the database file.

Can someone tell me what to do to let saveContext method save records in the same order those are inserted to context?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but I am sure this is something related to indexing that is done by sqlite by itself.

Comment: You can't. Besides even a SQLite database is not necessarily stored in a given order. Especially not in the db file. Any order is inferred from the NSSortDescriptor in the query. Just as it is inferred from the ORDER BY in the sql query.

Comment: To add to what @Fogmeister wrote:

You would have to modify the code for both sqlite and core data to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reliably maintain order of your objects is to add an additional attribute on the object, such as 'index', and then set the value once the object has been created.  Use this object to sort the results when you retrieve them or use the index to retrieve the objects in the required order.

Comment: Right, and as Mundi points out the internals of how SQLite (or any other relational database) decides to store data is not transparent so the only way to retrieve data in a sequence is to attach some property which records the sequence ( you could use a timestamp if you don't want to keep a counter).  If you study the database file you can determine the order by looking at the timestamp.  Not sure why you don't think that's a perfectly practical way of addressing your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got the answer for my query. All I wanted to know was is there some property or something in core data for this which I am missing? but the answer is "NO". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to implement the `NSManagedObject` subclass's `awakeFromInsert` method and set a date property to `NSDate()`. Now you have a sequence which is accurate to 10,000th of a second. When you need items in order, just sort by this date property.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, but if you read my question carefully, you will find that I know how to fetch sorted data from core data. All I need to know is why sqlite file generated by core data don't save data in the sequence as it is inserted. As I need to study the sqlite db file some times.

Comment: As stated in the comments, there is no such concept as storing data in any particular sequence in a database, nor should you care about the order in which objects are stored. If you need this feature, you can export to some text file if that suits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the createdAt field with the date data type your entity
2. Add an extension to your entity

```html
extension WLSections {
    override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        self.createdAt = NSDate()
    }
}


extension WLSections {
  public override func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        self.createdAt = Date()
    }
}
```

Whenever you fetch the data just write in

```
  let sortedStocks = stocks.sorted { $0.createdAt! < $1.createdAt! }
```

Example code

```html
func fetchMySymbolsStocks() -> [WLStocks]? {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<WLSections> = WLSections.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", AppConstant.Feature.mySymbols)
    
    var aryData = [WLStocks]()
    do {
      let sections = try CDManager.shared.mainContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
      for section in sections {
        if let stocks = section.relationship as? Set<WLStocks> {
          let sortedStocks = stocks.sorted { $0.createdAt! < $1.createdAt! }
          return sortedStocks
          
          print("called")
          break
          /*for stock in sortedStocks {
            if let symbol = stock.symbol {
              aryData.append(symbol)
            }
          }*/
        }
      }
    } catch {
      print("Failed to fetch sections: \(error)")
    }
    return aryData.isEmpty ? nil : aryData
  }
```